# Filter list elements by symbols

Tags: python, list

Hi I want to filter elements with / without `-`, `.` into two lists. My code doesn't do the job, it seems run through everything twice and cannot replace both `-` and `.` at the same time. Where did I do wrong?

Code:

```
NO_SYMBOL = []
WITH_SYMBOL = []
SPACE = []
for i in DATA:
    for ch in ['-', '.']:
        if ch in i:
            WITH_SYMBOL.append(i)
            SPACE.append(i.replace(ch, ' '))
        else:
            NO_SYMBOL.append(i)
```

Data

```
['volunteer-abroad',
 'volunteer-abroad.com',
 'volunteer-abroad.ie',
 'volunteer-abroad.org',
 'volunteerabroad']
```

My output:

```
SPACE
['volunteer abroad',
 'volunteer abroad.com',
 'volunteer abroad.ie',
 'volunteer abroad.org',
 'volunteer-abroad com',
 'volunteer-abroad ie',
 'volunteer-abroad org']

NO_SYMBOL
['volunteer-abroad', 'volunteerabroad', 'volunteerabroad']
```

I want to get output like these:

```
SPACE
['volunteer abroad',
 'volunteer abroad com',
 'volunteer abroad ie',
 'volunteer abroad org']

NO_SYMBOL
['volunteerabroad']
```

Comment: Can you figure out why your list might be twice as long as you expected? Look at your loops. Well written question, by the way.

Comment: Well, when `i` is set to `'volunteer-abroad.com'`, you first take `'-'`, create a new string with just `-` replaced with spaces, and add that to `SPACE`. You then take `.` and do the same. Perhaps you need to first take care of all replacements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating those two characters separately, by using a `for` loop:

- The first time through the `for ch in ['-', '.']:` loop, `ch` is set to `'-'`. When that character is found in `i` you create a new string with `-` removed, and append that to `SPACE` and `i` itself is appended to `WITH_SYMBOL`. If the character is not found you append to `NO_SYMBOL`.
- The second time through the loop, `ch` is set to `'.'`, and you do all the same work again.

As a result, you always append to either `SPACE` and `WITH_SYMBOL`, or to `NO_SYMBOL` *twice* for each `i`.

You need to delay appending until you have processed all the characters in `ch`, and only when the loop is done decide where to append. You could use a flag variable for that:

```
for i in data:
    altered = False
    cleaned = i
    for ch in ['-', '.']:
        if ch in clean:
            altered = True
            cleaned = cleaned.replace(ch, ' ')
    if altered:
        SPACE.append(cleaned)
        WITH_SYMBOL.append(i)
    else:
        NO_SYMBOL.append(i)
```

You can also just test for *either* character to be present, and use `str.replace()` for both. It's safe to do so, `str.replace()` doesn't care if the character you are replacing is not present at all:

```
if '-' in i or '.' in i:
    SPACE.append(i.replace('-', ' ').replace('.', ' '))
    WITH_SYMBOL.append(i)
else:
    NO_SYMBOL.append(i)
```

Rather than use two `.replace()` calls you can also use a [*translation table* passed to `str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate); this is faster, and much more flexible if you have a variable number of characters to replace. For the latter case, you can use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to test for a sequence of characters:

```
symbols = ['-', '.']  # can be extended later
translation_map = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(symbols, ' '))  # map any symbol to a space
for entry in data:    # entry is a nicer name here than i
    # the following loops over symbols until one is found that matches, then 
    # returns True. If no matching symbol is found, False is given instead.
    if any(ch in entry for ch in symbols):
        SPACE.append(entry.translate(translation_map))
        WITH_SYMBOL.append(entry)
    else:
        NO_SYMBOL.append(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a loop to run twice on the same list instead you can modify the if condidition

```
NO_SYMBOL = []
WITH_SYMBOL = []
SPACE = []
for i in DATA:
    if '-' in i or '.' in i:
        WITH_SYMBOL.append(i)
        SPACE.append(i.replace('.', ' ').replace('-', ' '))
    else:
        NO_SYMBOL.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in your code was found by other answers - but by using a simple RegEx you would get more performance and could easily change it when you have to add new symbols to match:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("[-.]")
NO_SYMBOL = []
WITH_SYMBOL = []
SPACE = []

for item in data:
  if pattern.search(item):
    WITH_SYMBOL.append(item)
    SPACE.append(pattern.sub(" ", item))
  else:
    NO_SYMBOL.append(item)
```

Online demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/InfiniteOldlacePress)